# chromium browser: how to set print parameters (A4 / A3, orientation etc)?

Tags: css, printing, chromium

There are any way to add print parameters when using window.print() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the CSS3 rules:

```css
@page {
  size: A4 portrait;
  margin: 27mm 16mm 27mm 16mm;
  counter-increment: page;
  @bottom-right {
    content: "Page " counter(page) " of " counter(pages);
  }
}
```

But some user agents do not support the `pages` counter and will ignore any content that includes that counter, so to cover all UAs, do:

```css
@page {
  size: A4 portrait;
  margin: 27mm 16mm 27mm 16mm;
  counter-increment: page;
  @bottom-right {
    content: "Page " counter(page);
    content: "Page " counter(page) " of " counter(pages);
  }
}
```

Read more about the CSS3 Paged Media Module [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/CR-css3-page-20040225/#page-size-prop)